# Image uploads and attachments to Yahoo group don't work, despite completing upload process with no errors

Tags: yahoo-groups

Yes, someone still uses Yahoo groups...

There's an active  Yahoo group I'm a member of around an interest area which I'm trying to post details of something, but whenever I upload the images (on Chrome and Firefox), it seems to upload fine, then nothing happens:

- As attachments to a post, the green bar fills up all the way, it looks like the photos have attached, but when I then send the post, it sends without the attached images.
- As photos in a photo album, everything appears to work fine, but when I press "Post photos" after it says "Upload Complete!", nothing happens: the photos simply aren't there, and the album still just says:

  > There are no photos in this album. **Add Photos**

I've been through the ["Unable to post photos" help page](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2490.html) and eliminated all the normal likely causes:

- I am a member of the group
- I am allowed to post photos (there would be no option otherwise)
- The image files are not too large (well below the 10mb limit, and no error messages anyway)
- The yahoo group itself has enough space, it's using barely 1% of its allowed 100gb
- They are the right format (.jpg)
- There are no notices or messages about moderator approval

Tried on both Chrome and Firefox.

It seems like [I might not be alone in this problem](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Groups/Cannot-upload-or-attach-files-in-Yahoo-Group/td-p/108835/page/1), but that long thread seems to contain no answers or solutions, only complaints.

Currently my very crude workaround is to upload the images to an Imgur page, and post a link to that in my (empty) "photo album" description, but that's a bad workaround. What can cause this and how can I post photos so they actually show up?

---

I've found one possible clue: almost all photo albums created since December 2015 are strangely empty like mine, as if people posted the photos then didn't realise it hadn't actually worked. Some people do successfully post photos, but it looks like it has failed for the vast majority of people since December 2015. I can't see any obvious difference with the few it succeeds for.